# Displaying a list of tags in my archives page

Tags: search, tags, archives

I'm looking to display a list of tags on my archives.php page. [Here is the search archives page.](http://www.averylawoffice.ca/archives)

I have archives by month

```
<ul>  
<?php wp_get_archives(); ?>  
</ul>
```

Archives by category

```
<ul>  
<?php wp_list_categories(); ?>  
</ul>
```

and now I'm trying to look through the codex for a way to display a list of tag links but none of them do that. I just want them to do exactly what my list of categories is doing.

Why can't I find the right template tag for that? 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [tag cloud](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud).

Comment: I guess thats the only other option.